# Outputting object attributes in Ruby on Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a simple application to manage a database of bands and musicians in Rails, and I've been having an issue printing object attribute values in a view file.

The models are Band, Musician, which are connected by a join table to make a HABTM relationship. Here is my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170613125004) do

  create_table "band_musicians", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "band_id"
    t.integer "musician_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["band_id"], name: "index_band_musicians_on_band_id"
    t.index ["musician_id"], name: "index_band_musicians_on_musician_id"
  end

  create_table "bands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "musicians", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "instrument"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

I then inserted some seed data using the following seeds.rb script, which seemed to work fine.

```
band_data = [[name:"band 1", description: "band 1 description"],
             [name:"band 2", description: "band 2 description"],
             [name:"band 3", description: "band 3 description"],
             [name:"band 4", description: "band 4 description"]]

musician_data = [[name:"musician 1", instrument:"instrument 1"],
                 [name:"musician 2", instrument:"instrument 2"],
                 [name:"musician 3", instrument:"instrument 3"],
                 [name:"musician 4", instrument:"instrument 4"],
                 [name:"musician 5", instrument:"instrument 1"],
                 [name:"musician 6", instrument:"instrument 5"],
                 [name:"musician 7", instrument:"instrument 1"],
                 [name:"musician 8", instrument:"instrument 2"],
                 [name:"musician 9", instrument:"instrument 3"],
                 [name:"musician 10", instrument:"instrument 1"],
                 [name:"musician 11", instrument:"instrument 4"],
                 [name:"musician 12", instrument:"instrument 1"],
                 [name:"musician 13", instrument:"instrument 2"]]

band_data.each{|name, desc| Band.create(name:name, description:desc)}
musician_data.each{|name, instr| Musician.create(name:name, instrument:instr)}

bands = Band.all()
musicians = Musician.all()

bands.each do |b|
  r = Random.new
  bandSize = r.rand(2..5)
  bandSize.times do
    m = r.rand(0...musicians.length)
    b.band_musicians.create(musician_id: musicians[m].id)
  end
end
```

I then wanted to output the data to a view, so I created a Band controller:

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @band_data = Band.includes(:musicians).all
    @musician_data = Musician.all
  end
```

And this index.html.erb Band view:

```
<% @band_data.each do |b| %>
    <p>
      <%= b.name %>
      <br>
      <%= b.description %>
    <ul>
      <% b.musicians.each do |m| %>
          <li>
            <%= m.name %>
          </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <hr>
<% end %>
```

The database appears to have been seeded properly, but a Hash representation of each object is being output rather than the attribute values. 
This is what I'm getting:

```
{:name=>"band 1", :description=>"band 1 description"} 
{:name=>"musician 12", :instrument=>"instrument 1"} 
{:name=>"musician 1", :instrument=>"instrument 1"} 
{:name=>"musician 10", :instrument=>"instrument 1"}
```

When I want something more like:

```
band 1
band 1 description
 - musician 12
 - musician 1
 - musician 10
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: your seeds are wrong. One of the things you can do is to fix `band_data ` and `musician_data` arrays to contain hashes instead of arrays. For instance `band_data = [{name:"band 1", description: "band 1 description"},..` and in your loop: `band_data.each{|data| Band.create(name: data[:name], description: data[:desc])}`. And do the same for `music_data` array.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `key: value` syntax inside square brackets, Ruby is assuming you want a hash inside an array. There are many situations where curly brackets can be left out and Ruby will parse it as a hash anyway.

Also, you can pass an array of attribute to `Model::create` and it will create multiple rows at once. Usually not that useful, except for seed data.

```
Band.create [{name:"band 1", description: "band 1 description"},
             {name:"band 2", description: "band 2 description"},
             {name:"band 3", description: "band 3 description"},
             {name:"band 4", description: "band 4 description"}]

Musician.create [{name:"musician 1", instrument:"instrument 1"},
                 {name:"musician 2", instrument:"instrument 2"},
                 {name:"musician 3", instrument:"instrument 3"},
                 {name:"musician 4", instrument:"instrument 4"},
                 {name:"musician 5", instrument:"instrument 1"},
                 {name:"musician 6", instrument:"instrument 5"},
                 {name:"musician 7", instrument:"instrument 1"},
                 {name:"musician 8", instrument:"instrument 2"},
                 {name:"musician 9", instrument:"instrument 3"},
                 {name:"musician 10", instrument:"instrument 1"},
                 {name:"musician 11", instrument:"instrument 4"},
                 {name:"musician 12", instrument:"instrument 1"},
                 {name:"musician 13", instrument:"instrument 2"}]
```

So the answer is that you are actually rendering the view correctly, it was the seed data that was getting messed up.

If you get confused about why something is being rendered a particular way, an easy way to debug this is drop a `<% console %>` into the view and Rails will give you an interactive console at that location when it executes, allowing you to directly inspect the runtime environment.